# Android Login app with MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, login-script

I'm trying to create a login app by following a youtube tutorial. I created  a table using WAMP with a username and password entry. It should be showing "Login Success" message but I get "Login Status" message whenever I press the login button regardless of the input.

I've pasted all the code below. I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Background activity class code:

```
package com.example.klm.sql;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Background (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String user_name = params[1];
    String password = params[2];
    String login_url = "https://192.168.1.2/login.php";
    if(type.equals("Login")){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();


}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

MainActivity class code

```
package com.example.klm.sql;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etUsername, etPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

}
public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String type = "Login";

    Background background = new Background(this);
    background.execute(type, username, password);
}
}
```

Login php code

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = addslashes($_POST["user_name"]);
$user_pass = addslashes($_POST["password"]);
$mysql_qry = "SELECT * from `login_data` WHERE `username` = '$user_name' AND `password` = '$user_pass';";
$result    = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Login Succes";
} else {
    echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

Connection php code

```
<?php
        $db_name = "login";
        $mysql_username = "root";
        $mysql_password = "";
        $server_name = "localhost";
        $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name );
?>
```

Comment: `&_POST`? Plus, lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities...always a nice thing to see in login code.

Comment: you have use like operator....!!!!!

Comment: It should be `$_POST[]` and also check if any exception is raised..

Comment: I still get the same message even after the edit by Ali. I'll look into the sql injection vulnerability after fixing the login part.

Comment: as long as you don't forget it, what usually happens until ...

Comment: `addslashes()` is **NOT** a defense against injection attacks. at best it's a soggy piece of wet toilet paper. you're using mysqli. there's NO execuse for not using a proper prepared statement with placeholders.